# What kind of Rope for a Bosun's Chair

Tags: climbing, ropes, tree-climbing

I'm going to make a bosun's chair to lift me 40 ft in the air to a tree platform (with at least a 6' clearance, so closer to 50'). Of course I would like the right type of rope with the right tensile strength.

It might be useful to have a second line in case of the first one snapping, but the primary one would be for lifting and not falling.

Of course there will be pulleys involved so the rope needs to be able to make bends without degrading.

And it will remain outside most of, or almost most of the year in a climate with snow and ice and temperatures down to -20F once in a while; usually in the 10s and 20s in the winter. There will be sunshine typical of the temperate zone though the rope should be undercover in the growing season. The working load will probably be about 200 lbs., not counting the weight of the rope itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for any type of line that is meant for [running rigging](https://www.westmarine.com/WestAdvisor/Selecting-Line-for-Running-Rigging) on a sailboat. These lines are made to work with pulleys or block and tackle systems, they have very good strength with more than adequate working load limits, and they can withstand the weather for quite a while. The main idea is to have a polyester sheath for UV protection.

For a backup, I would go for a [climbing rope](https://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/ropes.html) as you need a dynamic rope than can absorb some of the shock from a fall. A simple Single rope would do fine. I wouldn't leave that backup outside, exposed to the elements though so make that removable.